# Branch-specific environment variable in Buildkite CI/CD pipeline

Tags: environment-variables, cicd, buildkite

I would like to define an environment variable called `ENVIRONMENT` as follows:

- if `BUILDKITE_BRANCH == 'main'`, then `ENVIRONMENT=production`
- if `BUILDKITE_BRANCH != 'main'`, then `ENVIRONMENT=staging`

I'd like this variable to be defined at the pipeline level if possible, since I have other pipeline variables that would depend on it.

Here's some pseudo-code to show what I would like to do:

```yaml
env:
  ENVIRONMENT: $(if BUILDKITE_BRANCH == 'main' then "production" else "staging")
  OTHER_VAR: other-var-$ENVIRONMENT

steps:
  commands:
    - echo $ENVIRONMENT
    - echo $OTHER_VAR
```

Does anyone have any creative solutions or work-arounds?

Comment: You could use a conditional check within a [hook](https://buildkite.com/docs/agent/v3/hooks#job-lifecycle-hooks)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

if [[ "$BUILDKITE_BRANCH" == "main" ]]; then
  export ENVIRONMENT ="production"
else
  export ENVIRONMENT ="staging"
fi
```